# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - June 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the ninth edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for June 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                  380
2   grg                        340
3   Allan                      290
4   fsb                        160
5   JBis                       130
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,531 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-06-02).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   grg                       93
2   bmike                     83
3   Nimesh Neema              66
4   Monomeeth                 62
5   IconDaemon                39
```

A big thank you to all 16 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,453
2   Monomeeth                 512
3   creidhne                  251
4   grg                       200
5   bmike                     182
```

A big thank you to all 55 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Mark                      65
2   Allan                     61
3   Monomeeth                 36
4   fsb                       32
5   nohillside                27
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                257
2   fsb                      117
3   Nimesh Neema              98
4   grg                       88
5   Melvin Jefferson          53
```

A big thank you to all 34 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                113
2   Allan                     96
3   grg                       35
4   Glorfindel                23
5   Tetsujin                  15
```

A big thank you to all 21 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     55
2   fsb                       21
3   grg                       17
4   Tetsujin                  13
5   Monomeeth                 12
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    20
2   Tetsujin                 11
3   Mark, fsb                10
4   grg, Monomeeth, JMY1000   6 
5   IconDaemon                3
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    54
2   Monomeeth                44
3   grg                      41
4   fd0                      16
5   Glorfindel, Nimesh Neema 14
```

A big thank you to all 28 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Can't see this emoji  on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328474/cant-see-this-emoji-on-macos)

   - Posted by: Jay Wong
   - Votes: **27**
2. [Can I add a “space” to my Dock to separate apps into groups?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327325/can-i-add-a-space-to-my-dock-to-separate-apps-into-groups)

   - Posted by: irelande
   - Votes: **21**
3. [Touch ID when “wants to make changes”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327025/touch-id-when-wants-to-make-changes)

   - Posted by: zored
   - Votes: **17**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Can't see this emoji  on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328474/cant-see-this-emoji-on-macos/328481#328481)

   - Posted by: Tom Gewecke
   - Votes: **42**
2. [Touch ID when “wants to make changes”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327025/touch-id-when-wants-to-make-changes/327026#327026)

   - Posted by: grg
   - Votes: **30**
3. [Can I add a “space” to my Dock to separate apps into groups?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327325/can-i-add-a-space-to-my-dock-to-separate-apps-into-groups/327327#327327)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **27**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Can you update to macOS 10.14 (Mojave) without converting to APFS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327051/can-you-update-to-macos-10-14-mojave-without-converting-to-apfs)

   - Posted by: JBis
   - Views: **2,478**
2. [Can't see this emoji  on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328474/cant-see-this-emoji-on-macos)

   - Posted by: Jay Wong
   - Views: **2,239**
3. [Install Homebrew packages on macOS Mojave Beta](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327458/install-homebrew-packages-on-macos-mojave-beta)

   - Posted by: iProgram
   - Views: **1,994**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grg)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grg)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2313/mark)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Jay Wong](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168096/jay-wong)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Tom Gewecke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49804/tom-gewecke)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [JBis](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/263848/jbis)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In June our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 400 flags with an average handling time of 28 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 289 comments
- deleted 274 posts
- closed 130 posts
- edited 291 posts
- created 156 posts
- created 506 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: My life is complete. I have made it to the AskDifferent Monthly report. :)

Comment: @JBis Haha, well, you've been rather active of late, so it's a natural reward! :) That aside, my personal preference would be to see new faces in the report *every* month. *Many hands make light work*, so to speak, and we all benefit from a healthy, vibrant community!